# UILabel in a cell doesn't break lines

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

My label is not breaking lines, it is displaying like this

> Text...

And I am expecting something like this

> Text
>
> &
>
> Text2

Here's my code

```
UILabel *oppLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(131, 10, 130, 21)];
oppLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
string  = [[Array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"O"];
NSString *string2 = [[NSString alloc]init];
string2  = [[Array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"P"];
string = [string stringByAppendingString:@"\n    VS\n"];
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@",string,string2];
NSLog(str);
oppLabel.tag =1;
oppLabel.text = str;
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines=0;
[cell.textLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[cell.contentView addSubview:oppLabel];
return cell;

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return 100;
}
```

Comment: Try to increase number of line oppLabel.numberOfLines  = any value > 1 or you can dynamically set numbers of line as per text.;

Answer (score 0):

1. You have set the oppLabel with a fixed frame height of 21 pixels and then adding this as a subview to the cell.
   This is going to be a problem since the frame height is fixed.
2. You are also setting cell.textLabel properties but not using the cell.textLabel
   Perhaps you don't nee oppLabel and should be setting the cell text directly?

Comment: Why do i need to set oppLabel frame height to 21?

Comment: You shouldn't - your problem is that you have already - the first line of your code!